# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Int32' while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, url-routing, razor-pages

In a ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages Web Site, I try to navigate from a list of bank account to the scaffolded edit page of a single bank account. The edit page does not open and the error message is displayed:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'System.Int32' while attempting to activate
>   'ForexWeb.Pages.BankAccountModel'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

The bank accounts page (BankAccounts.cshtml) is

```
@page 
@model ForexWeb.Pages.BankAccountsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BankAccounts";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Bank Accounts</h1>

<table>
    @foreach (var account in Model.BankAccounts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@account.AccountNumber</td>
            <td>
                <a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@account.Id">More</a>
                @*<a asp-action="Account/Edit" asp-route-id="@account.Id">Edit</a>*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The edit page (Edit.cshtml) starts with

```
@page "{id}"
@model ForexWeb.Pages.BankAccountModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BankAccount";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>BankAccount</h1>
```

The routing is setup in the Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);
}

private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
{
    routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/action=Index/{id?}");
}
```

The BankAccountModel class

```
public class BankAccountModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly int _id;
    private readonly IForexRepository _repository;

    public BankAccountModel(int id, IForexRepository repository)
    {
        _id = id;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public ForexRepository.Entities.BankAccount BankAccount { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        BankAccount =  _repository.GetBankAccount((int)id);


        if (BankAccount == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["BankId"] = new SelectList(_repository.GetBanks(), "Id", "Id");
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        var bankAccount = _repository.GetBankAccount(_id);
        BankAccount = bankAccount;
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _repository.AddBankAccount(BankAccount.BankId,BankAccount);

        try
        {
            _repository.Save();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!BankAccountExists(BankAccount.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }

    private bool BankAccountExists(int id)
    {
        return _repository.GetBankAccount(id) != null;
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BankAccountModel` is created by DI container. While creating page model the container is resolving all constructor parameters in order to inject them and create an instance of `BankAccountModel`. An exception is thrown when the container tries to resolve service of type `int` which apparently is not registered. So you need to remove `int` parameter from the constructor

```
public BankAccountModel(IForexRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```